# sort and delete data in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create the function, which will accept purchases, and return the table  with columns ordernumber and product_ID. I need to sort the result in descending order of the value price end negative  values of  vector quantity  must be removed.
Function example

```
sample.purchases <- data.table(price = c(100000, 6000, 7000, 5000000),
                               ordernumber = 1:4,
                               quantity = c(1,2,1,-1),
                               product_id = 1:4)
ordered.short.purchase.data(sample.purchases)
#   ordernumber product_id
#1:           1          1
#2:           3          3
#3:           2          2
```

I wrote code, but it does not work

```
ordered.short.purchase.data <- function(purchases) {
  purchases[order(price, quantity >= 0 , decreasing = T), list(ordernumber,product_id)] 
}
```

Comment: You''ll probably need to pipe it as you can't combine both order and filter in the same expression, something like `purchases[quantity >= 0][order(-price), .(ordernumber, product_id)]`

Comment: If you don't mind ascending order and having an extra column for price, you could also use ```keyby```: ```sample.purchases[quantity >= 0, .(ordernumber, product_id), keyby = .(price)]```

Comment: Another possibility is `sample.purchases[order(-price), .SD[quantity>=0, .(ordernumber, product_id)]]` but might be slower than David's method